# Libgdx: game camera coordinates system inconsistent

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, sprite

I am having problems with my coordinates system. what I wanted to achieve is the the starting point of (0,0) is at the middle of the screen not in the lower bottom of the screen. I am encountering a problem on which involves the coordinates of the camera which my map appear smaller and my sprite bigger on screen and messes up the collision.

here is my code: [click here for the code](http://www.bpaste.net/show/c0U43PrFXAUGAST7xEu9/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
cam = new OrthographicCamera(10*(w/h), 10);
```

without using:

```
cam.setToOrtho(false, 10*(w/h), 10);
cam.update();
```

afterwards.